# Xamarin.Android support for OxygenOS

Tags: xamarin.android, oneplusthree

I am doing some research on running Xamarin.Android apps on OxygenOS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OxygenOS). Unfortunately, information online is scarce on the subject.

Appreciate thoughts on the subject. Specifically suggestions around following 2 questions:

1. Will Xamarin.Android apps work on OxygenOS?
2. If yes to the query above, are there any compatibility issues that one needs to be aware off?

Appreciate your help!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

After some research and web crawling, turns out OxygenOS, at least for now, will support any android app. It is essentially a custom ROM, as some blog post has suggested.

Reference

- https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/closed-does-oxygenos-supports-android-apps.329802/
- https://www.xda-developers.com/everything-oxygenos-what-we-know-what-to-expect/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OxygenOS

Comment: Please **quote and link** the information you have found to make it accessible for others searching for it, instead of just providing a summary of your view. Thanks!

Comment: @herrbischoff sure, have provided reference to some of the relevant articles that I came across during my research. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I would say that OxygenOS is nothing but the modified Android. Modified Android is still the pure Android as core, so I don't see any complication for any Android app works on pure Android X and doesn't work with OxygenOS built on Android X.

Now there should not be an issue how the Android app for Android X wad developed. And the app developed for Android X using Xamarin.Android will surely work on the OxygenOS built on Android X.